# Como agregar fondo (background) a PDF con librería itextpdf?

Tags: java, pdf, itext

Buen día.
No he podido agregar un background a mi reporte pdf con servlet y librería itextpdf, es una ppregunta sencilla que espero alguien me pueda ayudar

Agradezco quien me pueda colaborar.

```
            documento.open();

            Paragraph par1 = new Paragraph();
            par1.add(new Phrase("\n FACTURACION \n\n", titulo));
            par1.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
            documento.add(par1);

            Paragraph par2 = new Paragraph();
            par2.add(new Phrase(pg.facturaPDF(numFact), factura));
            par2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED);

            documento.add(par2);

            documento.close();
```

Comment: Qué versión de iText usas?

Comment: Hola, uso itextpdf-5.5.9.jar

Answer (score 0):

Por si acaso, iText5 está deprecado según el [readme](https://github.com/itext/itextpdf) y recomiendan usar [iText7](https://github.com/itext/itext7)

Hay [una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51558609/236345) por allí donde un usuario indica que es innecesariamente complejo. Pone este código de ejemplo para *ponerle color de fondo* al PDF... pone un rectángulo del color que le indica, con el tamaño de la página

```
//Class that creates the PDF
public class PdfCreator {

//Helper class so we can add colour to our pages when we call it from outer class
private static class PageBackgroundsEvent implements IEventHandler {
    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent) event;
        PdfPage page = docEvent.getPage();

        PdfCanvas canvas = new PdfCanvas(page);
        Rectangle rect = page.getPageSize();
        //I used custom rgb for Color
        Color bgColour = new DeviceRgb(255, 204, 204);
        canvas  .saveState()
                .setFillColor(bgColour)
                .rectangle(rect.getLeft(), rect.getBottom(), rect.getWidth(), rect.getHeight())
                .fillStroke()
                .restoreState();
        }
    }

    //PATH_OF_FILE is the path that the PDF will be created at.
    String filename = PATH_OF_FILE + "/myFile.pdf";
    OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(filename));
    PdfWriter writer = new PdfWriter(outputStream);
    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(writer);
    pdfDoc.addEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.START_PAGE, new PageBackgroundsEvent());
    PageSize pageSize = pdfDoc.getDefaultPageSize();
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc, pageSize);
    document.close();
}
```

Esa misma respuesta enlaza [otro post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26688288/set-a-fix-background-image-for-all-my-pages-in-pdf-itext-asp-c-sharp) donde hablan de cómo poner una imagen (y que no quede sólo en la última página), y proponen (en C#, eso sí) hacer un override de algunas cosas:

```
class ImageBackgroundHelper : PdfPageEventHelper {
    private Image img;
    public ImageBackgroundHelper(Image img) { 
        this.img = img;
    }
    /**
     * @see com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper#onEndPage(
     *      com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfWriter, com.itextpdf.text.Document)
     */
    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
        writer.DirectContentUnder.AddImage(img);
    }
}
```

y así, cada vez que finalice una página, va a usar la imagen que se le dé

```
string imageFilePath = parent + "/Images/bg_image.jpg";
iTextSharp.text.Image jpg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilePath);
jpg.ScaleToFit(1700, 1000);
jpg.SetAbsolutePosition(0, 0);
writer.PageEvent = new ImageBackgroundHelper(jpg);
```